# Is there a way to get Foursquare photos without oauth token. (with only App_ID, and App_Secret)?

Tags: ios, foursquare

The documentation says this request does not require an acting user, but it will only work with an acting user: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos

Comment: hey citizenglish, please mark the answer as accepted so that other people know that it fixed the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that it doesn't need an 'acting user' but if you click the 'Learn More' link right next to it in the docs, you can see that you still have to provide a **client_id** and a **client_secret** of your app. After you created an app you can use the Client ID and Secret to execute the following request:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos?client_id=INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&v=20140130
```